# What is causing fstream::open to fail here?

Tags: c++, winapi

## The Problem

I'm working on a simple Notepad app in Win32 C++. However I've run into a problem opening a file to save to. There is quite a bit of code (which you can find [here](https://github.com/nasrattakoor/Notepad-by-Nas.git)) but the line causing the error is in the file `Event Handlers.cpp`.

Specifically, line 25

```
wnd.file.open(wnd.filePath, std::ios_base::out);
```

throws an exception. Here's the debug output:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->**_Ptr** was nullptr.
```

though `_Ptr` isn't always the value `nullptr`.

---

## What I've Tried

That's the gist of the problem. Now here is what I've tried so far.

- checking the result of the Save-As dialog (the value of `wnd.filePath`) - it is indeed the correct file path string
- flushing, clearing, closing the file stream before opening it
- changing the open mode
- I thought maybe `fstream` objects cannot be global, since I was noticing the `std::filebuf` member was always NULL for global fstreams but not local ones. That wasn't actually an issue.
- and a LOT of other things over the past few days that unfortunately I can't remember

---

## My Theory

However, I believe the problem to be in the design of my code and the `std::fstream` class.

Line 34 in `Main.cpp`:

```
mainWnd = TopLevelWnd(wr.left, wr.right, wr.left, wr.top, 1280, 720, wr.right - wr.left,
   wr.bottom - wr.top, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
   0, L"Main Window Class", L"Main Window", hInstance);
```

constructs a `TopLevelWnd` and then *copies* it to the default-constructed `TopLevelWnd` in the global vector `windows`. From what I can tell, class `std::fstream` has its copy-members deleted and cannot be copied. This should produce a compiler error, since it is a member of `TopLevelWnd`, but it doesn't. In any case, I decided to delete `TopLevelWnd`'s copy-members and write move constructor and move assignment operator functions and call them explicitly with `std::move`:

```
    // delete copy members because fstream cannot be copied
    TopLevelWnd& operator=(const TopLevelWnd&) = delete;
    TopLevelWnd(const TopLevelWnd&) = delete;
    
    // move members
    TopLevelWnd(TopLevelWnd&& source)
        : Wnd(std::move(source)),
        file(std::move(source.file))
    {}
    TopLevelWnd& operator=(TopLevelWnd&& right)
    {
        Wnd::operator=(std::move(right));
        file = std::move(right.file);
        return *this;
    }
```

This doesn't fix the problem either, so I'm at a complete loss. Can someone help me understand?

P.S. By the way, to recreate the problem, you just run the program and in the menu, go to File->Save and pick a file to save to.

Comment: What's the call stack/backtrace when the debugger breaks at `Exception thrown: read access violation`?  That should provide some useful info regarding the point in your own code that may be the issue.

Comment: @G.M. the line I already mentioned - Line 25 in `Event Handlers.cpp` - `wnd.file.open(wnd.filePath, std::ios_base::out);`

Comment: The error is implying that either `wnd` or `wnd.file` is not a valid object in memory, thus calling `open()` on it would be *undefined behavior*. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the error in action.

Comment: "constructs a TopLevelWnd and then copies it to the default-constructed TopLevelWnd in the global vector windows". It's behind your learning curve now. winapi is not c++

Comment: @RemyLebeau `wnd` is valid for many other operations and `wnd.file` works for opening files when the user clicks the menu item `File->Open`, so I don't think that's the issue. If someone could run the program in a debugger and inspect it a little, I think that would be a big help.

Comment: @NasratTakoor "*I don't think that's the issue*" - then we will have to agree to disagree. Your symptom is very much characteristic of an invalid object being accessed. "*If someone could run the program in a debugger and inspect it a little, I think that would be a big help*" - that is YOUR job to do. StackOverflow  is a Q&A site, not a debugging service. Again, I ask you for a [mcve]. Asking people to download and run code from another site is not appropriate here.

Comment: See *"Iterator invalidation"* in the documentation for [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging and experimentation, I finally found the answer. The problem was in the `TopLevelWnd` constructor.

```
TopLevelWnd(int x, int y, int ncX, int ncY, int width, int height, int ncWidth, int ncHeight, DWORD styles, DWORD exStyles, const wchar_t* className, const wchar_t* name, HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandleW(nullptr), HWND hWnd = nullptr, HWND hWndParent = nullptr, HMENU hMenu = nullptr)
        : Wnd(x, y, ncX, ncY, width, height, ncWidth, ncHeight, styles, exStyles, className, name, hInstance ,hWnd, hWndParent),
        hMenu(hMenu)
```

It took two parameters named `hWnd` and `hMenu`. The class also has two data members called `hWnd` and `hMenu`. In the body I was writing lines like:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowExW(...);
hMenu = CreateMenu();
```

when I needed to write

```
this->hWnd = CreateWindowExW(...)
this->hMenu = CreateMenu();
```